# Batch file - Property File in Classpath not being read

Tags: batch-file, properties, classpath

Got a classic batch script to launch a jar, where I set up my classpath

```
set CP=%CP%;some.property
set CP=%CP%;some.jar
```

And when launching my jar

```
start java.exe -cp %CP% my.class.main args
```

It doesn't read the property file I've passed in the classpath and tries to read the one in the main .jar

What could be wrong here? The path is correct, I've double checked it.

Answer (score 0):

I was adding the file and not the folder of the file in the classpath.

Don't:

```
set CP=%CP%;folder/conf/file.properties
```

Do:

```
set CP=%CP%;folder/conf/
```